# How to hide block after click Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

There is an block HTML in page:

```
<div class="item" ng-click="delete();"></div>
```

Angular JS:

```
$scope.delete = function (){
   if(confirm){
   // hide block
   }
}
```

I can send `$event` to function `delete($event);` and then using Jquery hide block, how to do it in Angular JS?

Comment: Usually, when deleting, you simply... delete the *"item"* from the collection and your view will update.

Comment: How delete element from array, when i know attribute with value id: 8?

Comment: Get the index of it using either .some, .every, .filter, or .forEach, and then use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array

Comment: You could also pass the index to your delete method using `$index` `<div class="item" ng-click="delete($index);"></div>`

Comment: After in function i need delete by `$index` like as `array.splice(index, 1);`?

Answer (score 0):

To use jquery use like this `$(element)` -> `angular.element(element)`

Try this to remove a element:

```
angular.element(this).remove();
```

Comment: however, never do this in a controller.